# Traverse path cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I am using rest api of neo4j  in my php application , my requirement is to find the related nearest  nodes  from one node say "2"  and  The nodes need to find  are related  using relation "road_to".

Its like  finding nearest locations from one location at level one and then two and so on.All locations are attached  using path  "road_to".

I have cypher query  to find  but

1) It gives nodes repeatedly which i dont need.

2) I  need to give limit  to what extent nodes are required to display,here in query  i have to give ()-[:road_to]->()  again and again for which i need to give some limit for levels

```
start n=node(2) Match (n)-[r:road_to]->()-[:road_to]->()-[:road_to]->(foaf) return r,foaf,n
```

Any help would be appreciated .Thanx

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest way to collapse multiple hops is by using a limited variable length path, like this:

```
MATCH (n)-[:road_to*1..3]-(foaf)
WHERE id(n)=2
RETURN n, foaf;
```

Notice that I got rid of the `START` clause in favor of `MATCH` with `WHERE id(n)=2`.  They're basically the same though.   Here the operator `[:road_to*1..3]` matches between 1 and 3 hops of the `:road_to` relationship.  Put whichever limits you like in there, and read more about this approach [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_relationships_in_depth) in the "variable relationships" subsection.

If you want to find the SHORTEST link that meets some criteria, then you can do that like this:

```
MATCH (n), (foaf),
  p = shortestPath((n)-[:road_to*..15]-(foaf))
WHERE id(n) = 2 AND foaf.someProperty=someValue
RETURN p
```

Here we're binding the path to `p`, so if you want the individual relationships inside of that path, you can get them with other cypher functions.  Also notice that I'm looking for a particular `foaf`, not just any.  In general when you're looking for the shortest path you're looking for the path to a particular node.  If you have many nodes linked by `:road_to` then without this extra criteria, you'd just get one hop.

More on shortestPath [can be found here](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-match.html#_shortest_path).

Comment: Thanx for reply , i tried it this is what i am already getting but the problem is repeated nodes in result